# How to use @Library in an imported groovy script in Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

What I have is a following:

1. global shared library created as described [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). Nothing special, one script in `vars` folder called `deleteFile.groovy`, tried it - works. Library is called `myOneLib`
2. a pipeline script called `firstPipe.groovy`

```
@Library('myOneLib') _

def execute(String zCmakeListsPath){
    stage('some kind of stage 2') {
        echo "Hello from stage 1 with " + zCmakeListsPath
        echo "var attempt ${env.mySrcDir}"

    }
    stage('second stage'){
            echo "and one from stage 2"
            echo "param was " + zCmakeListsPath
            echo "var attempt ${env.myBuildDir}"
            //call function from global lib
            deleteFile 'for 3rd party global library now'
    }
}

return this
```

3. a pipeline script called `caller.groovy` that is calling `firstPipe.groovy`

```
pipeline {
    agent any
     environment {
            myBuildDir = "thisShoulbBeBuild"
            mySrcDir = "andHereIsSrc"
        }
    stages {
        stage('first') {
            steps {
                script{
                    echo 'beggining with ' + myBuildDir
                    def rootDir = pwd()
                    echo 'rootDir is ' + rootDir
                    def example = load "${rootDir}/fullPipe/firstPipe.groovy"
                    example.execute("rasAlGhul")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I run the build like this, I get the following error:

> ERROR: Could not find any definition of libraries [myOneLib]

but when I simply move the line `@Library('myOneLib') _` to the top of `caller.groovy` everything works.

So my question is how do use the `@Library` in the imported/included script? Or is there some other way to specify the global library?

Few more notes: `caller.groovy` and `firstPipe.groovy` are in the same git repo, and if I eliminate usage of the global library, everything works fine. I'm using declarative pipeline and would like to continue to do so.

Comment: It is probably easier to use the `library` step to dynamically load in the imported script to handle some of the oddities with how the Jenkins Groovy runtime works.

Comment: @mkobit Thanks a lot for the hint, I cannot believe I missed that https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically Will you promote your comment to answer? Or is my question too easy and obvious and I should delete it? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this use case, it will make more sense to use the `library` step to dynamically load it at runtime.

In your `firstPipe.groovy` you could do something like:

```groovy
final myOneLib = library('myOneLib')

def execute(String zCmakeListsPath){
  stage('some kind of stage 2') {
    echo "Hello from stage 1 with " + zCmakeListsPath
    echo "var attempt ${env.mySrcDir}"

  }
  stage('second stage'){
    echo "and one from stage 2"
    echo "param was " + zCmakeListsPath
    echo "var attempt ${env.myBuildDir}"
    //call function from global lib
    myOneLib.deleteFile 'for 3rd party global library now'
  }
}

return this
```

See the [*Loading libraries dynamically* section of the *Extending with Shared Libraries* documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically).

Comment: Is there any workaround if I use Jenkins Pipeline version lower than 2.7?

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko I'm assuming you are talking about the [`Pipeline Shared Groovy Libraries Plugin`](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Shared+Groovy+Libraries+Plugin), but I cannot think of an elegant one. You could require that users use the `@Library` in their pipeline to bring it on the classpath, or pass those methods or classes down into the other levels. Those just seem like hacky workarounds.