# Calling one parametrized job (aka "template" ) from many other jobs - is this a feasible approach?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have jobs like this:

- template__build_docker
- build_dockerA
- build_dockerB
  ...
- build_dockerX

template__build_docker is a parametrized job, like this:

```
node {
   [string(name: 'docker_name', trim: true)]

   ... build the container - git clone, etc ...
}
```

each of the build_dockerA, build_dockerB... do this :

```
stage('call build template'){
   build job: 'template__build_docker ',  parameters: [string(name: 'docker_name', value: 'MyDockerImageA')]                                  
}
```

I know this is a little clunky, and that using declarative pipelines I could use master pipelines (did not look into details) but that is what I am working with.

QUESTION: Is this a feasible approach or are there any concerns with this that would make this a improper way to achieve pipeline reuse / refactoring?

I know of already one issue - if I quickly start a few build_dockerX jobs, more then the configured "# of executors", then I ran into deadlock - the jobs cannot start the template job since no executor is available.

or there other gotchas like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is YES, but you should use [shared libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). Look at a simple example written [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-global-variables), or the [one where there is whole declarative pipeline defined](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-declarative-pipelines) and used from a jenkinsfile. I remembered also a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306383/how-to-use-library-in-an-imported-groovy-script-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline) I posted here on SO which could also serve as an example.

As far as "gothas" go, I think that it is still impossible to load one jenkins library from another. Other then that it's perfect.